# Unexpected result using WebDriver's findelements(By.cssSelector) method in loop

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver

I am using WebDriver to verify elements on a page by css selector. With the following method 'checkTablesByHeader' that I have created.

```
public static void checkTablesByHeader(WebDriver driver, String[] columnHeaderValues, String tableID, String selector){
    String elementSelector = "#" + tableID + " "+selector; 
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(elementSelector));
    int i = 0;
    for (WebElement e : elements){
        Assert.assertTrue(e.getText().contains(columnHeaderValues[i]));
        i++;
    }
```

My problem lies with using this method in a loop as seen below. The first pass works perfectly and only grabs nine elements in the List. The second pass should have the same exact number, but is returning 300 + elements. I am doing this because I have tables that have very similar structure, but only different ids. I have checked and rechecked that the id on the second pass can only possibly return 9  elements with the current code.

```
    for(int i=1; i<6; i++){
    SeleniumUtil.checkTablesByHeader(driver, stringArrayNine, ("mqContent_a_" + i), "th");
    }
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code...
How I would debug this:
1. Step into the code and get the exact value of "elementSelector" on the second pass.
2. Grab Firefox, install the Firebug and Firefinder plugins
3. Navigate to the page in question
4. Paste the value of "elementSelector" into Firefinder
5. Review Firefinder results
5. [If applicable] write up a bug on the WebDriver site